# How to start master and slave on EMR

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm new to EMR and now I can't run my Spark application on EMR.
My question is how I can $start-master.sh and $start-slave.sh on EMR.
I put this 2 commands into a bash file and upload to S3 for bootstrap.

```
aws emr create-cluster --release-label $release_label \
--instance-groups InstanceGroupType="MASTER",InstanceCount=$instance_count,InstanceType=$instance_type,BidPrice=0.2,Name="MASTER" \
InstanceGroupType="CORE",InstanceType=$instance_type,InstanceCount=$instance_count,BidPrice=0.2,Name="CORE" \
--auto-terminate \
--use-default-roles \
--name knx-attribution-spark-$product-$environment-$build_number \
--log-uri s3://knx-logs/emr/knx-attribution-spark-$product-$environment \
--ec2-attributes KeyName=$keypair,SubnetId=$subnet,EmrManagedMasterSecurityGroup=$sg1,EmrManagedSlaveSecurityGroup=$sg1,AdditionalMasterSecurityGroups=$sg2,AdditionalSlaveSecurityGroups=$sg2 \
--tags Name="knx-emr-attribution-spark-$product-$environment" Environment=$environment \
--applications Name=Spark Name=Hadoop\
--bootstrap-actions Path="s3://${BOOTSTRAP_FILE}" \
--steps Type=Spark,Name=Stage,ActionOnFailure=CONTINUE,Args=[--deploy-mode,client,--packages,org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.3.0,--driver-memory,8g,--executor-memory,4g,--num-executors,4,--py-files,s3://${FILE_ZIP},--master,spark://127.0.0.1:7077,s3://${BUCKET}]
```

the bootstrap file is:

```
./spark/sbin/start-master.sh
./spark/sbin/start-slave.sh spark://127.0.0.1:7077
```

and it always throw this error:

```
/emr/instance-controller/lib/bootstrap-actions/1/install_lib.sh: line 4: start-master.sh: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the the .sh files are executable before you try.

If not try this command to make it as an executable:

```
chmod +x start-master.sh
```

And then try running the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run Spark on Amazon EMR in standalone mode.

Answer (score 0):

On EMR, Spark is run on YARN rather than in Standalone mode. Unless there’s something else wrong that I’m not seeing, the only thing you should need to change is to remove “--master,spark://127.0.0.1:7077” from the arguments of your spark-submit step. The correct args to use would be “--master,yarn”, but that is the default on EMR, so you don’t need to specify that.